# Modifying a globally defined static variable from a static method's mouse listener

Tags: java, static, global-variables, static-methods

I'm trying to modify the following globally defined variable:

```
static int players;
```

from the following method:

```
public static void selectPlayers() {

    JButton player1 = new JButton("1 Player");
    player1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            players = 1;
        }
    });
}
```

This has no effect on the variable.  The variable is global so that it can be accessed from the main method.  What is the best way to go about modifying the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, players is an attribut not a method. and accesing a static attribut have to be through the name of his class

```
public Class1{

 static int players;

 public static void selectPlayers() {

   JButton player1 = new JButton("1 Player");
   player1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Class1.players = 1;
    }
 });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the correct `players` variable, you need to call it in its proper location, in other words whichever class it is defined in.

if it is in the same class, call `this.players = 1`. If it is in another class, you should call `className.players = 1`. If your code compiles, it means you are modifying either a local variable or a global variable in the same class, while the one you need is in another.

Comment: Note that it's a static variable.

Comment: The use of `this` is legal but misleading.